# Why do I get a Error 500(Server Error) page when adding 'max_age' parameter to Google Oauth 2.0 URL?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-openid, openid-connect

The 'max_auth_age' doesn't work for me in a few days ago but it worked before.

I find that [OIDC](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html) has a 'Authentication Request' parameter named 'max_age', and the description fits what I need - re-authentication (means REQUIRES to input account/password each time).

It really asks me to input account/password each time after I add the 'max_age=0' parameter. But the Error 500 page is shown instead of redirect back to my page after I logined successfully. What the page says is as the below.

```
500. That’s an error.
There was an error. Please try again later. That’s all we know.
```

Does anyone have any idea what happen?

Comment: I wonder if it has something to do with the OpenId shutdown in a few days.   https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenID2Migration

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google OpenID Connect: Receiving a 500 error when supplying the "max\_age" parameter to an authentication request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748579/google-openid-connect-receiving-a-500-error-when-supplying-the-max-age-parame)