# Prompt user to enter password - Google OpenID Connect

Tags: google-openid, openid-connect, google-oauth

We are trying to use Google's OpenID Connect for a business web app but are concerned that the user will leave the app open and an unauthorized user will sign-in because the user is still signed into Google so OpenID Connect just let's them right in.

<s>We've tried using `max_auth_age=0` parameter.</s> This has been replaced by `max_age` in OpenID Connect.

I do see that Google App's control panel at admin.google.com does usually re-prompt the user for a password while any other login won't. But looking at the authorization URL I don't see anything that would be triggering this to happen.

Here is our current authorization URL:
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?prompt=select_account&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email+https%3A%2F%2Fwww....com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.profile&state=%2F&redirect_uri=https://www.foo.com/callback&response_type=token&client_id=...`

Perhaps if we added a certain scope that could trigger Google to go into high security mode, but I haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to control re-authentication as indicated in: [Google OpenID Connect: Receiving a 500 error when supplying the "max_age" parameter to an authentication request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29748579/google-openid-connect-receiving-a-500-error-when-supplying-the-max-age-parame) nor step-up as recorded in: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-federated-login-api/KT6pSp4VNaQ

Comment: Thanks, also want to add this as a reference http://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-specs-ab/Week-of-Mon-20150323/005445.html which explains the reasoning.
From our standpoint we will have to add our own authentication test to make sure the real user is on the other end.

Comment: another thing to be aware of is that the parameter is called `max_age` in OpenID Connect (it used to be `max_auth_age` in OpenID 2.0)

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect that. I'm still curious how admin.google.com manages to get me to enter my password most of the time. Very rare that it doesn't.

Comment: Updated URL for first comment: https://lists.openid.net/pipermail/openid-specs-ab/2015-March/005445.html