# Google OAuth-2 how to ask user for a password on each login?

Tags: google-oauth

I need to ask user for a password each time he using Google OAuth.
There was an option I have used "**max_auth_age**", but it stops working. 
Is there any replacement for this option. If not - could you please suggest where can I submit something like "feature request" to Google to restore this feature.
Thanks.

**UPD**
I have read possible duplicate topic and tried to use **max_age** instead **max_auth_age**. It did not help.

p.s I know that the main idea of OAuth2 not to use any passwords prompts, but its customer requirement. He is afraid that person, who not allowed to use system can have access on shared computer if someone forgot to logout from Gmail.

Comment: you should not be asking a user for there password at all this defeats the purpose of Oauth2 completely.    The only thing that is close would be approval_prompt=force it will tell them they need to re-authenticate your application.  https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prompt user to enter password - Google OpenID Connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627766/prompt-user-to-enter-password-google-openid-connect)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from BCM and ehsan s' concerns, it is possible to revoke access to your application AND ask for a password on subsequent login attempts.

Following is a NodeJS example with googleapis, but is simple enough to work for all applications:

```
const google = require('googleapis').google;

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    'client_id',
    'client_secret',
    'redirect_uri'
);

// Sign-in code (omitted) here

async function signOut() {
    return await oauth2Client.request({
        url: 'https://accounts.google.com/Logout',
        method: 'GET'
    });
}
```

Unlike oauth2Client.revokeCredentials, requesting https://accounts.google.com/Logout will make google ask for password on subsequent sign-in attempts.

Bare in mind that this request will sign the user out of all google services on the client.
This wont affect other clients on the device however - i.e. sign-out of NodeJS app will not cause the user to be logged out of gmail in Chrome browser running on the same machine and under the same user.

Hope this helps :)